# How many string object will be created in constant pool

Tags: java, string, logging, log4j

Consider following statement and log level is set to ERROR. Logging API being used is log4j.
How many strings will be created given above information?

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Executing SQL query [" + sql + "]");
}
```

Other question is

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
     StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder("Executing SQL query [");
     sBuilder.append(sql);
     sBuilder.append("]");
     logger.debug(sBuilder.toString());
}
```

How many string will  be created in above case ?

My question is will compiler create strings even if logger is not enabled for debug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
logger.debug("Executing SQL query [" + sql + "]");
```

Two strings

```
"Executing SQL query [" 

"]"
```

created at compile time.

And then, in Runtime,

```
"Executing SQL query [" + sql + "]"
```

(+) operator `JVM` returns new StringBuilder(string...).toString() which creates a **new String** instance in heap memory.

Append operation will happen with `StringBuilder.toString` ,If debug enable.

Comment: Will these be loaded at run time as well ?

Comment: @Jabir Ofcourse, That's a simple java lines,weather it is logger or what ever. At least I believe so.

Comment: @Suresh I have modified question slightly can you please check now

Comment: @Jabir The same thing, two Strings created. and one resolved at run time.

Comment: @Jabir Please prefer to read, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586266/is-chain-of-stringbuilder-append-more-efficient-than-string-concatenation

Answer (score 2):

If you have quotes in your source code, then the compiler will put the string constant in the pool, no matter how complicated the code is. The compiler doesn't make many assumptions except when it can clearly see that code is unreachable (like `if(false)`).

You may want to have a look at slf4j with logback which allows you to write

```
log.debug("Executing SQL query [{}]", sql);
```

Note that at runtime, it will still create a `StringBuilder` and build the result from the pattern and arguments but slf4j will do the `if` for you. That will keep your code clean and fast without a lot of effort.

You might want to look at [project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) and their [@Log annotation](http://projectlombok.org/features/Log.html) to make it even easier and more compact.