# Avoiding unnecessary value inputted seconds must convert to minutes, seconds, hours, days in JAVA

Tags: java

Write a java code for converting the seconds to minutes, seconds, hours and days. *But no value of 0 should be printed.*

****For example :****

> If the user gives 102, program should print 1 minutes 42 seconds .
>
> NOT  1 minutes 42 seconds 0 hours 0 days.

But I have written a code which show '0' value. Like, If the user gives 102,
the program  print, 0 day(s) 0 hour(s) 1 minute(s) 42 second(s).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class clock {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please input seconds");
    int seconds = keyboard.nextInt();
    int minute,hour,day;

    minute = seconds/60;
    seconds = seconds%60;
    hour = minute / 60;
    minute = minute % 60;
    day = hour / 24;
    hour = hour % 24; 
    System.out.printf("%d seconds and %d minutes %d hours %d days",seconds,minute,hour,day);
  }
}
```

That's also fine even if someone can give me the algorithm :)

Comment: you can use a StringBuilder with an if-else

Comment: So what you're saying is... **if** hours is zero then don't print it, and **if** days is zero don't print it, right?  (The hint is in this comment.)

Comment: can you be please more specific, if it's not bothering ? actually I am a new learner.

Comment: Sounds like a learning exercise.

Comment: Makoto practically gave you the answer short of writing the code for you. 
second hint, read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score -2):

You need to only print values if they are not 0. So you need to check if a value is zero. You do this using an `if`-statement like this:

```
if( day == 0) {
  // Code here will only execute if the value of day is zero
}
```

Or, if you only want to trigger if the value is *not* zero, you do a check that `day != 0`.

This way, we can build up a string that only has values that are not zero:

```
String output = "";

// First the days
if( days != 0 ) {
  output += days + " days";
}

// Then the hours
if( hours != 0 ) {
  output += hours + " hours ";
}

// etc
```

Then when you've finished, you can print the resulting line.

```
System.out.println(output.trim());
```

We call the `trim()` method to get rid of any extra whitespace on the beginning or end of the line.

Note that if you're using numbers, and the number can be negative, you  might want to check that `days > 0` instead of just not equal. Otherwise you might be printing `-1 days` which is weird.

Answer (score -2):

Yahoo ! Get the answer ! PROBLEM IS SOLVED VERY EASILY !!!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class clock {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please input the seconds");
    int seconds = keyboard.nextInt();
    int minutes, hour, day ;   
    minutes = seconds / 60; 
    seconds = seconds % 60; 

    hour = minutes / 60; 
    minutes = minutes % 60;

    day = hour / 24 ;
    hour = hour % 24 ; 

    if (seconds >0){
         System.out.printf("%d Seconds ",seconds);
    }
    if (minutes > 0){
         System.out.printf("%d Minutes ",minutes);
    }
    if (hour > 0){
         System.out.printf("%d Hour ",hour); 
    }
    if (day > 0){
    System.out.printf("%d day ",day);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Make an edit to your code :

public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

```
  System.out.println("Please input seconds");
  int seconds = keyboard.nextInt();
  int minute,hour,day;

  minute = seconds/60;
  seconds = seconds%60;
  hour = minute / 60;
  minute = minute % 60;
  day = hour / 24;
  hour = hour % 24; 
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); //This is used based on your requirement for dynamic output,each of the below conditions will add chars to string accordingly
  if(seconds != 0){
   sb.append(seconds +" seconds and ");}
  if(minute !=0){
   sb.append(minute +" minutes ");}
  if(hour != 0){
   sb.append(hour +" hours ");}
  if(day != 0){
    sb.append(day +" days");}
  System.out.printf(sb.toString());
```

}

Comment: You should provide a helpful explanation to supplement the code suggestion, i.e. what you changed and why it is needed

Comment: Is there any way to code this without using String Buffer and String Builder Classes ?????

Comment: you can use string concatenation , but string buffer uses less memory and faster in handling strings.

Comment: That is actually [not the case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46513041/419705) in Java 9 anymore, and code that went out of its way to use StringBuilders actually takes a performance hit now that Java has gotten smarter about how it handles string concatenation. :)