# Concatenates numbers in Java 8 for the Single quotes and commas

Tags: java, java-8

I am new to **Java 8** and looking to implement below in Java 8 only.

I have the following numbers

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
```

I want to convert all these numbers like '1111','2222','3333','4444' The list of numbers can be anything and it should be dynamic

I developed code like below, but only servers half purpose

```
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("111", "2222", "3333", "4444");
        String collect = numbers.stream().map(n -> n).collect(Collectors.joining(",'"));
        System.out.println(collect);
```

**Output:**

```
111,'2222,'3333,'4444
```

Comment: Read the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-. Also, what do you think map(n -> n) does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("111", "2222", "3333", "4444");
String collect = numbers.stream().map(n -> "'" + n + "'").collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(collect);
```

Comment: That's the correct way of doing it, but there is also the ghetto way: `String collect = "'" + numbers.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','")) + "'";` (why ghetto? because it's bad design and it won't work properly with 0 length array)

Comment: @kajacx If you have an alternative solution, it would be better to post it as an answer, than as a comment under someone else's answer.

Comment: Nah, as I said: it is a bad solution, I just commented it for fun and to see the comparision between good and bad design, not because people should use it.

Comment: @kajacx or even `joining("', '", "'", "'")`.

Comment: @AndyTurner well that’s preferable if you can preclude empty streams.

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it, using a `StringBuilder` and a custom collector:

```
String result = Arrays.asList("111", "2222", "3333", "4444")
            .stream()
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    StringBuilder::new,
                    (sb, s) -> sb.append('\'').append(s).append('\'').append(","),
                    StringBuilder::append,
                    sb -> {
                        sb.setLength(Math.max(0, sb.length() - 1));
                        return sb.toString();
                    }));
```

Comment: The collector "contructor" accepts a finalization method as an optional 4th argument? I never knew that, +1 for random usefull info.

Comment: Isn't this just a "bit"  unefficient?

Comment: Can't you just return `sb.toString()` from the finalizer?

Comment: @Eugene "return sb.toString()" after trimming the comma.

Comment: @NiVeR inefficient? exactly how plz?

Comment: First of all code-wise, and probably also computationally (though is not easy to say exactly).

Comment: @NiVeR it actually should outperform `StringJoiner` and thus your solution easily.

Comment: Extracting the Collector.of..., the sb ->{} lambda parts to separate methods will surely make it more readable. It's surely more "efficient" memory wise but doesn't read very fluently :/

Comment: @Sneh *to you* it's not; it's an entire different story after 3 years with java-8...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a normal `for` loop is still faster than streams, so you should use that if performance is critical, while you should use streams where you can afford to be 2-3 times (I'm guessing) slower for the sake of code readibility.

Comment: @kajacx  [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49466784/1059372) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48624167/1059372) . when playing with concat and String, `StringBuilder` is still the one to go with; and the second point - streams are not slower (they are by a fraction) once code is hot enough

Comment: Keep in mind that streams may be empty. Besides that, you’ve just re-invented the `StringJoiner` and `joining` collector…

Comment: @Holger by accident I did, just looked up the sources today in detail

Comment: @Eugene my point was that if you joined the strings together with a StringBuilder in a for loop it would be faser than using a stream. The first link you provided has no info on this comaprision whatsoever, while the second link has much more additional stuff like taking only strings of certain length or taking only unquie strings, so the results are not that usefull. Also, what do you mean "once code is hot enough"?

Answer (score 0):

```
String numbers = Arrays.asList("111", "2222", "3333", "4444").stream()
    .map(number -> "'" + number + "'")
    .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

This will give you

```
"111,'2222,'3333,'4444"
```

As suggested in comments, you can also do it by directly creating a stream with the numbers rather than making a list and then a stream.

```
Stream.of("111", "2222", "3333", "4444")
        .map(number -> "'" + number + "'")
        .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList("111", "2222", "3333", "4444").stream()` is better off as `Stream.of("111", "2222", "3333", "4444")...`

Comment: I know but tried to keep it same as what OP posted. :) I will edit my answer anyway.