# Java - StringBuilder vs Concatenation of strings

Tags: java, stringbuilder, string-concatenation

The question is simple, what is better for avoiding of non-appropriated memory using? For example, let's say that we've a `String s = "Test"` and we'd like to add `1` to it so it becomes `Test1`. We all know that `s` gets a memory location and if we use `StringBuilder`, `Test1` will get a new memory address or it'll remain at `s`'s place, and what if we use `concat`?

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java) could be helpful.

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 5):

One line concatenations are optimized and converted to `StringBuilder` under the hood. Memory wise is the same thing, but the manual concatenation is more concise.

```
// the two declarations are basically the same
// JVM will optimize this to StringBuilder
String test = "test";
test += "test";

StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
test.append("test");
```

On the other hand, if you don't do trivial concatenations, you will be better off with `StringBuilder`.

```
// this is worse, JVM won't be able to optimize
String test = "";
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    test += "test"; 
} 

// this is better
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    builder.append("test"); 
}
```

Comment: [for the record, some real numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49466784/1059372)