# Understanding Invokedynamic Instruction in Java Bytecode and Its Impact on the Operand Stack

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, invokedynamic

I'm seeking clarity on how the `invokedynamic` instruction operates in Java bytecode. To illustrate, I've prepared a simple Java code snippet utilizing lambda expressions, which typically leads to the generation of the `invokedynamic` instruction upon compilation:

```java
public class App{
    public static void main(String... args){
        Runnable r = () -> {};
        r.run();
    }
}
```

Upon compilation with `javac`, the following bytecode is produced:

```java
0: invokedynamic #7,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:run:()Ljava/lang/Runnable;
5: astore_1
6: aload_1
7: invokeinterface #11,  1           // InterfaceMethod java/lang/Runnable.run:()V
12: return
```

As I understand, after the `invokedynamic` instruction, the operand stack should contain a `CallSite` (the result of the bootstrap method), which is subsequently stored onto the operand stack. Then, this `CallSite` is stored into a variable and executed.

However, the description of the `invokedynamic` method on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_bytecode_instructions) states:

> [invokedynamic instruction] invokes a dynamic method and puts the result on the stack (might be void);

This statement, particularly "might be void" has left me confused. Does this imply that a bootstrap method may not necessarily return a `CallSite` at all? Despite my attempts, I haven't been able to find any Java code snippet that generates the `invokedynamic` instruction without placing any values on the operand stack.

Could someone clarify whether it's possible for the `invokedynamic` instruction to not place anything onto the operand stack, including the `CallSite`? I've reviewed related answers on StackOverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638735/whats-invokedynamic-and-how-do-i-use-it), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139737/using-invokedynamic-what-is-going-on-under-the-hood),  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512888/how-is-string-concatenation-implemented-in-java-9), but none explicitly address the state of the operand stack. Additionally, I've attempted to find a bytecode debugger to check the operand stack state, but to no avail.

Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When in doubt check [the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokedynamic) and not some secondary source trying to explain the spec. The `CallSite` will never be null. The *return value* might be void.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand what `invokedynamic` does.

`invokedynamic` does not push a `CallSite` onto the stack. The *operands* of the `invokedynamic` instruction refers to a method that returns a `CallSite`. In the case of lambda expressions, this is the [`LambdaMetafactory.metafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F21%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory(java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup,java.lang.String,java.lang.invoke.MethodType,java.lang.invoke.MethodType,java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle,java.lang.invoke.MethodType)) method.

`invokedynamic` calls this `CallSite`-returning method (`metafactory`), gets a `CallSite`, then calls the target method handle indicated by `CallSite`. If this method handle needs arguments, things on the operand stack are popped. Finally, the result of calling this method handle is pushed onto the stack.

In this case, the call site returned by `metafactory` refers to some method that does not take arguments, and returns an implementation of `Runnable`. `invokedynamic` pushes this `Runnable` onto the stack. It is then stored into a local variable, loaded from that same variable (`astore`, `aload`), and its `run` method is called with `invokeinterface`.

`metafactory` takes a few arguments, and you might be wondering how `invokedynamic` knows what arguments to pass. Part of it is just "built into" `invokedynamic`, and the rest is stored in the [`BootstrapMethods`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se22/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.23) attribute of the class file.

Roughly translating this into Java code, the whole process looks like this:

```
Runnable r = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(XXX)
    .getTarget().invokeExact();
```

where the arguments "XXX" are in the `BootstrapMethods` attribute.

As another example, string concatenation uses `invokedynamic` too. This time, the operands will refer to one of the methods in `StringConcatFactory`. The method will return a `CallSite` representing some method that will return the concatenated string. For an expression like `"Foo" + System.nanoTime() + "Bar"`, `invokedynamic` would do something like:

```
StringConcatFactory.makeConcatWithConstants(XXX)
    .getTarget().invokeExact(System.nanoTime())
```

For more info, see the [JVMS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se22/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokedynamic).

Comment: It’s worth noting that the result of the bootstrap method, e.g. `LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(…)`, is remembered after the first invocation and reused in subsequent operations. And regardless of what this linking procedure does, the `invokedynamic` instruction has a formal type like every invocation instruction. In the example, `invokedynamic #7,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:run:()Ljava/lang/Runnable;` has the type `()Ljava/lang/Runnable;`, so the verifier knows in advance that the instruction will not pop any arguments and push a `Runnable`, even if the actual link target is not known