# How to use stringBuilder

Tags: java, string, option-type, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I have a function and Technical Leader review code and said :
Why this if statement? It's basically the same message. If you want customized, use a string builder with the type.
How to change it , can someone help me?

```java
private Optional<String> validatePrimaryPath(SalesChannelType salesChannelCode, List<String> primaryPathList) {

  if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(primaryPathList)) {
    if (salesChannelCode.equals(SalesChannelType.HEB_TO_YOU)) {
      return Optional.of("Customer Hierarchy is mandatory field for HebToYou.");
    } else {
      return Optional.of("Customer Hierarchy is mandatory field.");
    }
  }

  return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: I would not use a `StringBuilder` for this - or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm more concerned about the raw types. I also would not use a `StringBuilder` here.

Comment: i do not understand why have to use stringBuilder here and how to use it.

Comment: I agree with @Scary Wombat. You could use a single Optional.of and append "for HebToYou" conditionally via ternary operator. Just a thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent writing the same (partial) string literal multiple times, you can:

- Use a constant for the common part:

  ```
  if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(primaryPathList)) {
      final String COMMON = "Customer Hierarchy is mandatory field";
      if (salesChannelCode.equals(SalesChannelType.HEB_TO_YOU)) {
          return Optional.of(COMMON + " for HebToYou.");
      } else {
          return Optional.of(COMMON + ".");
      }
  }
  ```
- Build the string using `StringBuilder`:

  ```
  if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(primaryPathList)) {
      StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder("Customer Hierarchy is mandatory field");
      if (salesChannelCode.equals(SalesChannelType.HEB_TO_YOU)) {
          buf.append(" for HebToYou");
      }
      return Optional.of(buf.append('.').toString());
  }
  ```

Personally, I would keep the code in the question, especially if you ever might need support non-English versions of the text, because in other languages the extra text might not go there.

Comment: Even when not using compile-time constants, I wouldn’t use `StringBuilder`, as it complicates the code for no benefit. In all Java versions up to Java 8, you get this code anyway when using `+`, and starting with Java 9, you get even better when using `+` (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54645780/2711488)). But I like the aspect of not having redundant `Optional.of` calls in the second variant. You can even [simplify the construct to a single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60635152/2711488)…

Answer (score 2):

Specifying two string literals implies that there is no runtime overhead. You can achieve the same using string concatenation, when all arguments are compile-time constants. In contrast, using a `StringBuilder` always implies a runtime operation. You can read more about the “`StringBuilder` is better than `+` myth” in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54645780/2711488).

You can generally reduce the syntactic complexity of you code:

```
private Optional<String> validatePrimaryPath(
    SalesChannelType salesChannelCode, List<String> primaryPathList) {

    final String prefix = "Customer Hierarchy is mandatory field";
    final String general = prefix + ".", forHebToYou = prefix + " for HebToYou.";

    return Optional.of(
            salesChannelCode.equals(SalesChannelType.HEB_TO_YOU)? forHebToYou: general)
        .filter(s -> CollectionUtils.isEmpty(primaryPathList));
}
```

This emphasizes that you are doing the same, just with slightly different data and uses the semantic of `Optional` instead of an `if` statement. And the actual code doesn’t need changes, if you decide the externalize the actual strings.

Note that if `SalesChannelType` is an `enum`, there is no need for `equals`, you can just use `salesChannelCode == SalesChannelType.HEB_TO_YOU` then.

Answer (score 1):

First, **please** don't use raw types. Second, I do not agree that using a `StringBuilder` to build the message is an improvement; however, since that is what you want I will show you what was likely intended. Something like,

```
private Optional<String> validatePrimaryPath(SalesChannelType salesChannelCode, 
                List<String> primaryPathList) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(primaryPathList)) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                    "Customer Hierarchy is mandatory field");
        if (salesChannelCode.equals(SalesChannelType.HEB_TO_YOU)) {
            sb.append(" for HebToYou");
        }
        sb.append(".");
        return Optional.of(sb.toString());
    }

    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Note that I have specified the method returns an `Optional<String>` and takes a `List<String>` when you write `Optional` and `List` without specifying the type then you are using raw types.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think your code is OK but I have a suggestion for this if you still want to use `StringBuilder`

```
private Optional validatePrimaryPath(SalesChannelType salesChannelCode, List primaryPathList) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(primaryPathList)) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Customer Hierarchy is mandatory field.");
        if (salesChannelCode.equals(SalesChannelType.HEB_TO_YOU)) {
            sb.insert(sb.length()-1, " for HebToYou");
        }
        return Optional.of(sb.toString());
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```