# When it is Declared String Builder vs string

Tags: java

When you decere like this . Are the instances created?

```
String string = "a"+"b"+"c";
```

Should it be declared like following?

```
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
sBuilder.append("a");
sBuilder.append("b");
sBuilder.append("c");
```

Answer (score 1):

For

```
String string = "a"+"b"+"c";
```

The compiler generates a complete string.  The bytecode looks like
this.  Most compilers would do it this way since it is working with constants.  Variable concatenation may be handled differently depending on the version of the JDK.

```
  0  ldc <String "abc"> [16]
  2  astore_1 [string]
```

So the following would be unnecessary overhead.

```
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
sBuilder.append("a");
sBuilder.append("b");
sBuilder.append("c");
```

However, if you ever need to call append on the same `StringBuilder` object you can do the following:

```
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
sBuilder.append("a").append("b").append("c");
```

`StringBuilder.append` returns its own instance.

Comment: Older versions of the JDK would have compiled the string concatenation into a `StringBuilder` anyway, assuming not all the operands were string literals (as in the OP's example). Newer versions use [`StringConcatFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.html). The point being that `StringBuilder` really only makes sense if you're building a string in a loop or something similar.

Comment: @slaw Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Here's a relevant Q&A: [How is String concatenation implemented in Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512888/how-is-string-concatenation-implemented-in-java-9).

Comment: The golden rules
1) Never, ever optimize your code
2) If the profiler tells you to do it, break rule 1