# Java String Concatenation using '+' operator

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

What does actually happens when we concatenate a string `S2` of size `Y` to a string `S1` of size `X` ( already present on the heap) using the `+` operator?

This is what I think:

If I execute the following function:

```
class StringConcatenation{

    String S1;

    String concat(String S2){
       this.S1 = this.S1 + S2;
    }
}
```

If `S1` was present in the string pool (which is stored in the heap) and we execute the concat method, then the method gets executed on the stack.

So, the CPU will need to copy the `S1` in the stack => **READ `S1`**

As strings are immutable, Java must make a new object (let's name its reference as `S3`).

Now, contents of S1 and S2 are copied at new object => **COPY `S1` + COPY `S2`**

Then the reference S1 points to the new object.

Therefore, the total time complexity is O(**READ `S1`** + **COPY `S1` + COPY `S2`** ) = `O(X + X + Y)` = `O(2*X + Y)`.

Is my thought process correct?

Comment: Looks OK to me. Except `O(2*X + Y)` would usually be written as `O(X + Y)`, as big-O discards multiplicative constants (that's kind of the point of it).

Comment: Seems correct, yes

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html money quote: "For example, the javac compiler may implement the [+] operator with StringBuffer, StringBuilder, or java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory depending on the JDK version. " so it may *not* be the case.

Comment: "will need to copy the S1 in the stack" does not make any sense - Strings are never copied to the stack - only their references.

Comment: @GyroGearless, can you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Why you READ S1 and then COPY S1 afterwards?? Both Strings will live on the heap, and remain there, the new object instance will also be created on the heap. In Java, only references (and primitives) are handled on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) you can read:

> The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to strings. String concatenation is implemented through the StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method.

```
a = a + b is the equivalent of a += b or:

a = new StringBuilder()
    .append(a)
    .append(b)
    .toString();
```

Comment: That reference is rather old... Since Java 9, [the concat operator (`+`) doesn't always mean that a `StringBuilder` is used under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46513041/180719).

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer:* The `String` class has undergone multiple changes to improve performance and space utilization. What happens when JIT compiles code is then entirely undefined. The following is a simplification, and ignores any optimizations that may or may not be applied.

`String` is a class that encapsulates a `char[]`. The array length is always exactly the `length()` of the string. The class, and the underlying array, is immutable.

```java
class String {
    private final char[] arr;
}
```

`StringBuilder` (and `StringBuffer`) is another class that encapsulates a `char[]`, but the array is almost always larger than the number of characters in the array. The class, and the array, is mutable.

```java
class StringBuilder {
    private char[] arr;
    private int len;
}
```

When you do string concatenation with the `+` operator, the compiler generates that as:

```java
// Java code
s = s1 + s2 + s3;

// Generated code
s = new StringBuilder().append(s1).append(s2).append(s3).toString();
```

`StringBuilder` will initially create the array with length 16, and will re-allocate the array when needed. Worst case is that `s1`, `s2`, and `s3` are all too large for the current array, so each `append()` call needs to re-size the array.

This means that the would progress as follows:

1. `new StringBuilder()` - Creates `char[16]`.
2. `append(s1)` - Resizes `arr`, then copies chars from `s1.arr` to the array.
3. `append(s2)` - Resizes `arr`, copies existing content (chars from `s1`) to new array, then copies chars from `s2.arr` to the array.
4. `append(s3)` - Resizes `arr`, copies existing content (chars from `s1` and `s2`) to new array, then copies chars from `s3.arr` to the array.
5. `toString()` - Create new `String` with `char[]` sized to exactly fit the characters in the `StringBuilder`, then copies the content (chars from `s1`, `s2`, and `s3`) to the new `String`.

All-in-all the chars from `s1` ends up being copied 4 times.

If the string concatenation is `S1 + S2`, like in the question, then the characters from `S1` are copied 2 or 3 times, and the characters from `S2` are copied 2 times.

Since time complexity is generally *worst* case, that means *O(3m + 2n)*, not the *O(2m + n)* suggested in the question. Of course, Big-O eliminates constant factors, so it is actually *O(m + n)*.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas for such a comprehensive answer.