# Will Java update Strings on creation

Tags: java, string, jvm, string-concatenation

Since Strings are immutable in Java, will this create 3 objects, or will it internally create only one object.

How the execution will happen in the JVM and will it depend on the JVM implementation?

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        String s = "FirstString" + "SecondString" + "ThirdString";

    }
}
```

If the above case resolved in the compile-time how the below case works.

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        String s = "FirstString" + "SecondString" + args[0];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this example

```
String s = "FirstString" + "SecondString" + "ThirdString";
```

the 3 constant strings concatenated with `+` make up a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29). What this means is that the compiler can know the exact result of that expression at compile time and therefore inlines the result (i.e. the resulting `.class` file will look as if there was just a single constant with the content `FirstStringSecondStringThirdString`).

Note that the exact rules as to what counts as a constant expression are not quite intuitive, so check the JLS for details, if interested.

In

```
String s = "FirstString" + "SecondString" + someStringVariable;
```

the first concatenation will be "collapsed" into simply `"FirstStringSecondString"` and the third concatenation will be done the "normal" way at runtime.

The [*specific* way that String concatenation at runtime happens in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512888/how-is-string-concatenation-implemented-in-java-9) is quite complex and causes the relevant constant entry in the pool to be `"FirstStringSecondString\u0001"` (note the trailing `\u0001` to indicate where the argument goes). But it still demonstrates that the first concatenation in this expression is resolved during compilation from `.java` to `.class`.

This leads us to realize that even

```
    String s = "First" + "Second" + someStringVariable + "Last";
```

will be optimized into a single operation, since the constant used in this case is `"FirstSecond\u0001Last"`.

Comment: I don’t think that [the exact rules as to what counts as a constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29), i.e. “*A **constant expression** is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a `String` that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:*”, followed by an explicit list of constructs, is unintuitive.

Comment: @Holger: the primary reason it's unintuitive is that sometimes a field `x` is constant or not depending on when / how it was initialized. `final static int x = 3;` makes `x` a constant expression whereas `final static int x; static { x = 3 };` makes `x` *not* a constant expression.

Comment: Given that the `static {}` block could be anywhere in the source file and the assignment be buried between other statements, I think it’s not so much surprising that a compile-time constant requires an *initializer* that is always directly at the declaration, rather than an *assignment* that could be anywhere. Only deliberately placing the block directly after the variable declaration makes it look similar.

Comment: @Holger: yes, with enough know-how and understanding all problems become shallow. All the rules make sense when inspected in detail. But that's still quite a bit different from being "intuitive". Two examples that look very similar behave quite differently. That's what I'd call unintuitive.

Comment: Sounds like a self-fulfilling prophecy. Instead of spreading “enough know-how and understanding”, we discourage people by calling the rules “unintuitive”, only to find there are people not understanding the rules, indicating that the rules were unintuitive.

Comment: You know what: I've chosen the wording for my answer, heard your critique and chose to keep it. I stand by it. I chose that description based on the number of questions I see where people *are* confused by it.