# Where I can find Kotlin String plus method implementation?

Tags: string, kotlin

Where I can find Kotlin String plus method  implementation?
When I track who calls String#plus, why Intellij IDEA point to  "+" ? If String#plus is equal to "+", how does this implement?

Comment: For Kotlin/JVM, it is implemented within the compiler `javac.exe`. For constant expressions, its computed during compile-time already. I.e. `"hello" + "world"` is `"helloworld"` after compilation. Otherwise, before Java 9, it was `new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b)...toString()`. Since Java 9, there are more optimizations. Just take a look at your bytecode and you can see what it uses.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512888/how-is-string-concatenation-implemented-in-java-9 for details. Again (at least for Kotlin/JVM), this is implemented in the compiler `javac.exe`, which creates specific bytecode. This also means that the implementation can vary between the Java compilers out there (Oracle, OpenJDK, Eclipse, ...).

Comment: Srting::plus is an operator function, so `"str1".plus("srt2")` is equal to `"str1" + "str2"` if its what you asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the answer.

1. Where I can find Kotlin String plus method implementation?

Here I quote answer of ilya.gorbunov who is the member of JetBrains Team member.

> "Currently, navigation to builtin sources may not work as expected in maven/gradle projects.
> You can find sources of builtins here kotlin/core/builtins at master·JetBrains/kotlin· GitHub 171.
> Note that the ‘native’ part of them do not have implementation bodies, as they are implemented as compiler intrinsics.
> If you’re more interested in what they are compiled to, you can inspect the generated bytecode with the “Show Kotlin bytecode” action."

Link is here [Browsing source code of kotlin.kotlin_builtins like the .. operator](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/browsing-source-code-of-kotlin-kotlin-builtins-like-the-operator/2055)

2. When I track who calls String#plus, why Intellij IDEA point to "+" ?
   If String#plus is equal to "+", how does this implement?

The "+" operator is implemented by "Operator overloading" of Kotlin. When view String.kt source code, you can see the below code.

```java
package kotlin
public class String : Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
    companion object {}
    /**
     * Returns a string obtained by concatenating this string with the string representation of the given [other] object.
     */
    @kotlin.internal.IntrinsicConstEvaluation
    public operator fun plus(other: Any?): String
    // omitting some source code 
}
```

Parameter of String#plus method is Any?, meaning we can use "+" operator concatenate any object after string object. Details of "Operator overloading" you can refer to [Operator overloading Kotlin's Doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#binary-operations)